# Mobile test automation for iOS and Android

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation, nunit, automated-tests

I wonder if you have any mobile test automation tool that you can recommend? After trying several tools I simply cannot find one that meets every criteria. Ranorex can be used on both devices but after facing too many issues I have chosen not to use it. The best tool I have encountered is robotium, although it only works on Android and therefore is not interesting.

**Criteria:**

- Possible to CI integrate.
- Can be used with Nunit or a similar structure.
- Can be used on both iOS and Android.
- Is stable.

Please do not recommend one of these recording tools, since they (in my opinion) do not test anything.

Have a nice day an thank you for all the help.

Comment: Did you already try out appium?

Answer (score 2):

Automation of applications on real devices for Hybrid/Native/Mobile Web can be achieved by using **Appium** which is an open-source framework.

Appium allows you to create once and use everywhere capability for mobile web apps, e.g., same script would be running on Android as well as iOS.

Its rich function library support enables you to automate even complex mobile application gestures e.g., tap, pinch, precise tap, swipe etc.

For more details on appium, visit: http://appium.io/

Comment: If choosing Appium, I'd recommend using Java (another benefit of Appium is that it supports many languages) as it's the most popular / easiest to get support with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Tosca Mobile+** would be of interest for you:
http://www.tricentis.com/tricentis-tosca-testsuite/tosca-mobile-plus/

Tosca follows a model based approach - it's not script based, and it's also not a Capture & Replay tool. The identification of the controls is done via technology-related properties and IMHO the most reliable way for a stable automation.

Beside of Android & iOS, Tosca does support many more technologies (UI and Non-UI).

Tosca can also be completely integrated into your CI (using e.g. Jenkins, TeamCity, QuickBuild or any other build tool).

For more details you can also look at the **Tosca Mobile+ Documentation:**
https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/840/index.htm#tbox/mobile.htm%3FTocPath%3DTBox%7CTosca%2520Mobile%252B%7C_____0

Answer (score 0):

May be it is bit late to answer this question - you can try M-eux from Jamo Solutions. It works well for android and iOS. Supports native, hybrid and web apps on both android and iOS. Continuous integration is possible. By default there is no out of the box integration but you can write unit test cases in junit. Compile them and put them in CI using jenkins.
Other option could be seetest from Experitest. Same features are available with this tool as well. Both of these tools are not open source or freeware.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/). It can be used with both IOS and android and is easily integrated into a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SIGOS App Experience (formerly Keynote Mobile Testing/DeviceAnywhere)?

It integrates with many of the leading CI/agile tools including Appium, HP UFT, Selenium, and SAP. They offer testing on real devices and you can choose what type of deployment you want-- public cloud, private cloud, on-premise.

SIGOS App Experience also offers app performance monitoring, which not all test automation platforms do. [https://appexperience.sigos.com/](https://appexperience.sigos.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=website)